# Ruby/Watir : Unable to parse through xls Columns using the spreadsheet GEM

Tags: ruby, excel, watir

I am using the "Spreadsheet" GEM to parse through data in an xls sheet. The xls I am using has data similar to the one shown below :

[image]

I need to parse all the filled cells in one column and then move to the next column. I am using following code to achieve this :

```
sheet1 = book.worksheet 0
  sheet1.each do |row|
    break if row[0].nil?
    @browser.link(:href => row[1]).when_present.click
  end
```

How do I ensure the code parses all the cells in the first column and then moves to the next column once it finishes the first ? The code shown above is parsing only the first column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do the following:

```
sheet1 = book.worksheet 0
0.upto(sheet1.column_count) do |column|
  sheet1.column(column).to_a.compact.each do |cell_text|
    @browser.link(:href => cell_text).when_present.click
  end
end
```

Explanation:

- `sheet1.column_count` tells you how many columns there are.
- `sheet1.column(column)` gets a column at the specified index (0-based).
- `sheet1.column(column).to_a` gets all of the values in the column. The number of rows in a column is based on the column with the most number of rows. Therefore, some of the columns are likely to have blank value at the end. The `.compact` is used to remove these.